# Why I get this error with angular and leaflet

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I set in separated files different components, but when I aggregate a search input, I get this error in local:

```
angular.js:13424 Error: Map container not found.
```

and in plunker:

```
angular.js:13424Error: Map container is already initialized.
```

The strange thing is that the map works well. What's wrong?

[Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/QRV8bR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uv7TgQ8c9qNj36hRzFay?p=preview)

You have initialized the map twice, one in `BaseMapController` and another in `inputController`.

In `BaseMapController`, replace

```
_map = BaseMapService.mapElement();
```

with

```
$scope.map = BaseMapService.mapElement();
_map=$scope.map;
```

In `inputController`, replace

```
BaseMapService.AutoComplete(_searchInputId).bindTo('bounds', BaseMapService.mapElement());
```

with

```
BaseMapService.AutoComplete(_searchInputId).bindTo('bounds', $scope.map);
```

Hope that solve your problem.

**Update:**

In your demo, auto-complete works fine but it is not properly bound to map. For example if you search any place, you will not find this place on map. I have just resolve the error you have mentioned.

For auto-complete, you have used google API and for `basemap`, you have used `Leaflet`.

My suggestion is: Rather than mixing these both approaches, either use [Leaflet.GoogleAutocomplete](https://github.com/rmunglez/leaflet-google-autocomplete) or [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

Comment: But the service.js can do that?. service.js share the map variable to BaseMapController and Input.Controller. I need to do this, but in service.js?